# How to turn off spoken answers in Google Chrome on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: google-chrome, macbook

There is no advanced option under the three vertical dot settings menu and there is no search setting option under the gear settings icon using the Google Chrome browser version 61.0.3163.79 on my MacBook Pro.

As a result, I am unable to turn off the loud voice response to a Google Chrome search, and am unable to use the Google Chrome browser for any searches because that voice is so loud that it disturbs everyone near me, especially when I am at a library.

Answer (score 0):

- Do a simple search on Google.
- Next to the search tabs (images, videos, news etc.) There is a tab named **Settings**.

[image: Search Settings]

- Click on **Search Settings**.
- In the next page, find the 4th Setting, named **Spoken Answers** and change it to *Just show text*

[image]

Comment: I'm using the Google Chrome browser version 61.0.3163.79 on my MacBook Pro. Unfortunately, when I click on Search Settings (as shown in your diagram above), I only get the message "SafeSearch can help you block inappropriate or explicit images from your Google Search results. The SafeSearch filter isn’t 100% accurate, but it helps you avoid most violent and adult content," with the options to "Turn on SafeSearch" or "Lock SafeSearch." There is nothing there about turning off audio responses (which are usually very loud) to searches.

Comment: @geos What if you use the direct link [google.com/preferences](https://www.google.com/preferences) (change the .com according to your country). Also make sure you are singed in, in Google when you do that

Answer (score 0):

Search settings for desktop Chrome are now accessed by first doing a simple search and then clicking the gear icon near the upper right-hand corner of the results page.

It also worth mentioning how to disable voice output on Android Chrome, since the "Spoken answers" section doesn't show up in the regular settings menu.

1. Do a simple search.
2. Tap the 3 horizontal lines icon to the left beside the Google logo.
3. Tap Settings.
4. Tap the 3 dots at the upper right-hand corner.
5. Tap the checkbox that says "Desktop site".
6. Scroll down to the "Spoken answers" section and tap "Just show text".
7. Tap the Save button at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The secret to change this setting in chrome is to switch to desktop view. Then go to the bottom and click on settings and disable spoken answers. If you have it in mobile view and go to the bottom and click on settings it will not show this as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off spoken answers, 2023.

- Click on the three dots in upper right.
- Check desktop site.
- Do a search for anything you like, just get it to show a results page.
- Click on Google banner at the top.
- Go to the bottom of the page to settings and tap on it.
- Click on search settings.
- Click on Other Settings in the upper left.
- Turn off spoken answers.

There is no save button, so just delete tab or turn off desktop site and continue using. Sometimes it doesn't last long and you have to turn off spoken answers again.